# Make while loop PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, while-loop, row

here I come to you because I have a problem with my loop while, the content manages to loop but my css only works on the first text displayed. Here attached the code of my loop and a screenshot of the rendering.If you have any suggestions for corrections, I'll take it.

```
<?php while($row = $req->fetch()) { 

            ?>      

            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 text_dia">
                <h2 class="reference_dia"><a href="<?php $row['lien']?>" class="lien_reference"> <?php echo $row['reference']; ?></a></h2>
                    <h1 class="titre_dia"><?php echo $row['titre']; ?></h1>
                        <p class="description_dia"><?php echo $row['description']; ?></p>

                </div>

<?php }
    $req->closeCursor();    ?>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCPAr.png)

```
.text_dia {
    margin-left:-300px;
    margin-top:400px !important; 
}
.reference_dia {
    margin-left:-600px;
    margin-bottom:-35px;
    margin-top:30px;
    font-size :20px;
    color:black; 
}
.lien_reference {
    color:#0174DF;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.lien_reference:hover { 
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.titre_dia {
    margin-left:-378px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:black;
    font-size:21px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family:Times, Times New Roman, serif;
}
.description_dia {
    margin-top:-30px;
    color:black;
    margin-left:20px;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: How does your css look like?

Comment: Your HTML is completely incorrect. You cannot have a `li` in a `div` like that. You cannot just place a `h1` in a `ul` either.

Comment: There should only be one h1 and if you have more than one row that outputs from your while-loop that is also incorrect html. I would recommend you to redo your html so it validates correctly with help of: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: I added the css and made the changes.

Comment: Try to remove all negative values in your css. That's probably what messes things up.

Comment: Thank you all, by following all your advice I have succeeded. Thank you from the bottom of my heart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add div with row class after while directly.
Instead of ul h1, just use h1.
Using li without ul or ol tag make no sense, so i replaced your li by p tag

```
<?php while($row = $req->fetch()) {  ?>     

<div class ="row">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 text_dia">
    <p class="reference_dia"><a href="<?php $row['lien']?>" 
    class="lien_reference"> <?php echo $row['reference']; ? 
   ></a></p>
    <h1 class="titre_dia"><?php echo $row['titre']; ?></h1>
<p class="description_dia"><?php echo 
 $row['description']; ?></p>
 </div>
 </div>
<?php }
$req->closeCursor();?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code it works correctly, I just have to do the css because the other documents are not aligned with the first one. Again thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome, if you still have some issues with an alignment of items, just post it.

Comment: @chilldownhill if my answer helped you please click on correct sign on the top left side of the answer.